# How can I draw a Bezier line with Python?

Tags: python, bezier

I am very new to coding and I try to draw a Bezier line in a simple way using Python. What I have made so far is below

```
import numpy as np
A=(10,20)
B=(30,40)
C=(5,60)
t=np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
P0 = A * t + (1 - t) * B
P1 = B * t + (1 - t) * C
Pfinal = P0 * t + (1 - t) * P1
print(Pfinal)
```

but the error that I receive is

```
   line 6 , in <module>
   P0 = A * t + (1 - t) * B
   ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (10,)
```

any ideas please?

Comment: note that there is a dedicated nympy library for this called [bezier](https://pypi.org/project/bezier/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your support, but as I have already told I am very new to coding and  I tried by myself to do some projects in order to learn. I have started some youtube videos as well. Regarding pip files do you know how can I install them because I have tried and I couldn't. I use spyder for IDLE

Comment: If you're starting out, I can strongly recommend installing [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) instead, and then never touching pip again.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips:

Step 1) Double check your types.
You are setting A,B,C as *tuples*, and you are trying to perform a matrix multiplication on tuples, which is not correctly interpreted.
So, first define A,B,C as *arrays*.

```
A = np.array([10,20])
B = np.array([30,40])
C = np.array([5,60])
```

Step 2) Set correct shapes
A,B,C are 1-dimensional array. Reshape them as follows:

```
A = A.reshape(2,1)
B = B.reshape(2,1)
C = C.reshape(2,1)
```

Step 3) Create t with linspace and reshape it

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1).reshape(1,-1)
```

Step 4) Operate the multiplication

```
P0 = A * t + (1 - t) * B
P1 = B * t + (1 - t) * C
Pfinal = P0 * t + (1 - t) * P1
print(Pfinal)
```

Comment: @AggelosVassilakos You might consider accepting the answer.